# How to hide/remove Query String in php using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration-files

Eg :
https://int.theqtl.com/test/t1.php?id=2
change to

https://int.theqtl.com/test/t1.php

Answer (score 0):

I use this .htacces

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4&sub2=$5&sub3=$6&sub4=$7&sub5=$8 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$    /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4&sub2=$5&sub3=$6&sub4=$7 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4&sub2=$5&sub3=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$  /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4&sub2=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$     /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$    /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$     /index.php?ext=$1 [L]
```

And then you still can use `$_GET['ext'];`
And the the link for an a tag while look instead of this:

```
<a href="www.site.com/index.php?do=true?when=now" >do stuf</a>
```

will it looks like this:

```
<a href="www.site.com/true/now" >do stuf</a>
```